# Why are canvas.toDataURL() and context.drawRect(...) Type Errors: "not a function"?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to save the contents of a web page canvas element (not my design) through the console, but canvas manipulation methods aren't working. Non-interactive methods like canvas.getContext() and ctx.fillStyle() are fine, but canvas.toDataURL() and ctx.fillRect(...) are producing TypeErrors - "not a function". I've tried a few things to check:

```
canvas_array = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas');
console.log(canvas_array[0].toDataURL());
```

The above and below are broken.

```
ctx = canvas_array[0].getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle="fff000";
ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
```

This breaks too:

```
canvas_array[0].toDataURL;
```

Finally:

```
console.log(canvas_array[0].fillRect);
console.log(ctx.fillRect);
```

When I log what should be the uncalled methods, they're printing null.

Is it possible that the site author has removed the methods? I can draw a rectangle on a canvas I create on a fresh page.

Comment: @Pointy toDataURL looks like it should be used on the canvas element, and fillRect is used on the context,  both of which I'm doing...?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement

Comment: Yes you're right; sorry. I guess I don't do much `<canvas>` work lately :)

Comment: When I try your code in a snippet it works fine.

Comment: Please setup an [MCVE]. The code you have shown should break at second line if what you tell os true, and thus you shouldn't be able to see that e.g getContext() on l3 does work. Also, try to restart your browser without any extension, and try to remove everything unrelated from the page you are experiencing it until you find the culprit.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido, I broke up the code to show that it was different steps I tried, and added some extra context.